# Laravel One to One Polymorphic Relation

Tags: php, laravel, orm

There are 3 models and their respective tables

1.Customer - id, name

2.Address - id, name

3.ExternalMapping - model_id, model_type, external_id

How do I define the relation in Customer model that will give me the external_id in ExternalMapping model?

I tried this but it didn't work

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function cascades()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\ExternalMapping', 'external');
    }
}

class ExternalMapping extends Model
{
    public function external()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should review the documentation on polymorphic relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations

Comment: I tried the above code reading the documentation and couldn't get it to work. Can you help me with it? @Unflux

Answer (score 1):

You need one to one polymorphic relation. Not one to many relation. So do this.

```
 class Customer extends Model
  {
    public function cascade()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\ExternalMapping', 'external');
    }
  }

 class ExternalMapping extends Model
 {
    public function external()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
 }

 print_r($customer->cascade->external_id;)
```

Answer (score 0):

The column you're referencing on your `Customer` class is incorrect, you should be referencing the `model` column not the `external` column as you currently are:

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function cascades()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\ExternalMapping', 'model');
    }
}
```

That will tell Laravel to look for a column on your `ExternalMapping` table that has the name `model_id` with the `id` value of the current `Customer`.

Then to grab the `external_id`:

```php
$customer->cascades->external_id;
```